# Show Normals of Text Curves

Tags: bezier-curves, text-object

If I convert a text object to curves, there are no normals displayed for these curves in edit mode, even though 'Normals' check box is selected (both in 2.79 and 2.8[under overlays]). How do I enable normals for text curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you mean, you should change type of curve from 2D to 3D

Comment: Worked... thank you! But that's strange. 2d curves do have segment direction, which can be reversed. But there is no way to see it without changing the type to 3d.

Comment: mostly, 2D uses for generating shapes, where detection doesn't matter